# Problems with pool size of Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor (Spring Framework 4.3.9.RELEASE API)

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing some load tests agains my Spring application and now I'm a little bit confused about the configuration of the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. The documentation of the internally used `ThreadPoolExecutor` describes the `corePoolSize` as

> the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are  idle

and `maximumPoolSize` as

> the maximum number of threads to allow in the pool.

That obviously means that the `maximumPoolSize` limits the number 
of thread in the pool. But instead the limit seems the be set by the 
`corePoolSize`. Actually I configured just the `corePoolSize` with 100 an let the `maximumPoolSize` unconfigured (that means the default value is used: `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647`) When I run the load test I can see (by reviewing the logs), that the executed worker thread are numbered from `worker-1` to `worker-100`. So in this case the thread pool size is limited by `corePoolSize`. Even if I set `maximumPoolSize` to 200 or 300, the result is exactly the same. Why the value of `maximumPoolSize` has no affect in my case?

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
  taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
  taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("worker-");
  return taskExecutor;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your load tests are using more than 100 threads concurrently? You could perhaps rule that out by reducing core pool size to 1 and seeing if the available size increases beyond 1.

Comment: thanks for comments solve the problem